# Maintaining NURBS quality importing and exporting in and out of Blender

Tags: export, import, nurbs-surface

My planned workflow: SolidWorks -> Blender -> Keyshot

I export a SolidWorks file as .wrl format.

Import the .wrl file into Blender, create an animation, and export it as .abc format into KeyShot.

Apply material and render in KeyShot

The issue I'm having is when I import the .wrl file into Blender, it creates a jagged surface.
When I import this jagged model to KeyShot, it's still jagged and I am unable to apply the NURBS feature as well.

However, when I import a SolidWorks file directly into KeyShot, it maintains the NURBS model, with a choice of either triangles or NURBS.

**Solidworks into Blender via .wrl**
[image: SolidWorks model into Blender via .wrl]

**Blender model imported into KeyShot as .abc**
[image: Blender model imported into KeyShot as .abc]

**SolidWorks into Keyshot directly**
[image: SolidWorks into KeyShot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here starts with the import into Blender.

If you create a NURBS surface in SolidWorks, and then import it into Blender in WRL format, it will be converted into a mesh.

To be able to display the surfaces smoothed, Blender can smooth the normals of the mesh. So the smooth surface is a fake.

If you then export to Keyshot, you again export just a mesh, instead of NURBS, only KeyShot can't interpret the normals smoothed in Blender and you get an unsmoothed mesh.

So you would have to solve the first problem once.

Since all importers (including FBX) in Blender do not support NURBS, you have to rely on an [Addon](https://ambient.gumroad.com/l/stepper).

Exporting NURBS Surfaces to KeyShot is also possible, but only with [KeyShot for Blender Plugin](https://manual.keyshot.com/plugins/manual/blender/) (but requires KeyShot Pro for NURBS).

I know this doesn't solve your problem directly, but I hope I've given you some hints.

Comment: Blender's KeyShot plug in actually carries the smoothness over

Comment: @Yabusa Ah, even better, then I apparently still used an older version at that time. Great that you found a solution with it!

Answer (score 3):

i dont know if this would help but have you tried changing Normals> Auto Smooth? make sure auto smooth is correct or off for preventing sharp edges[image]

Comment: I tried checking and unchecking normals auto smooth and changing degrees with no outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Blender isn't CAD software. Therefore, you will have unsmooth edges on your model. For that, make sure you have **Shaded Smooth** in your model first, then Apply *Auto Smooth* as already mentioned in the answer above.

Note that you can make "NURBS" curves in Blender also through `Shift` + `A` > `Curves` > `Nurbs`.

If you really want a CAD workflow in Blender, recently, an addon came out that enables people to do it. See how in videos here (there's a new addon called **Real CAD**, and it's totally free): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92QmjS-xDaI https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u2mLh9ZmxU

Comment: The only reason I have blender in my potential workflow is to add the physics fluid simulation. I tried all the different solidworks out put files that blender can import.
The other thing is when I import the smooth modifier, it doesn't carry over to Keyshot (my rendering software)

Comment: @Yabusa If right-clicking and shading smooth doesn't work, you could apply the smooth modifier (By clicking the dropdown on the top bar of the modifier and pressing apply). Though just asking, if it's just a NURBS curve, why not just add it in blender>

Comment: What do you mean by if it's just a nurbs curve?
I work for a company that uses SolidWorks for product creation. The way I can import the file into Blender is through .wrl
If you know a better way of setting up my work flow, I'm open.
I just need blender for the physics simulation. The thing with the smooth modifier and shaded smooth is it's within blender. When exported to KeyShot, It looses the smoothening

Comment: @Yabusa Then it's technically not possible to do in blender... except one option, I think. (can't you smooth in keyshot). Did you try using RealCAD?